# Celery Flower - is it an option for a dark theme

Tags: celery, flower

Using celery flower tool, and wondered if theres any support for a dark theme out there.
Or is my only option is to edit the default css file myself and make it as i wish?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Flower does not have an option to change the L&F. However, it is an open-source project and I am sure many Celery Flower users would appreciate if you make a PR for it. Flower is based on [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/index.html) which has pretty simple template system.

Comment: Considering that Flower almost an inactive project, I thought you may be interested in a good alternative - [Leek](https://tryleek.com/).